# minimize html for print

Tags: printing, html

What's the best way to print an html file without getting all the junk in headers etc? I just want to see the content of the article.

I tried using an html-to-pdf option but I have no need to save a file. I only want a printed version. I'm also hesitant about using an ubuntu add-on or extension from third-party providers.

Any ideas? It doesn't need to be pretty. I just want to read content.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.  As such, your question is too vague to be precisely answered.  Could you provide more details as to what you already tried and found good / bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring print window up, go to the `options` tab, set the header and footer to be `--blank--`, and you are ready to go:

[image]

From now on you can simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to print the files pages, there is no need to change these options anymore.

Comment: You're welcome, you might consider accepting the answer if you think it was helpful to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Either print the html from a browser, or use one of `html2text`, `html2ps`

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this.

Comment: @David_Foerster The specific  details are ALWAYS the same: `man html2txt`, think, try, fail, repeat.

Comment: I agree personally, but AU values more elaborate answers than that and I think you would know that.